# Message sent to a deallocated instance when accessing a UIButton to disable it

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7

This is my code for creating a UIButton,

```
- (void) setNavButton
{
     self->_newbutton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"New@3x.png"];

     UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 46,57)] autorelease];

     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);
     CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true);
     CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);

     [imageView.layer setMinificationFilter:kCAFilterTrilinear];
     [imageView.layer setAllowsEdgeAntialiasing:YES];
     CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0,0, imageView.bounds.size.width+10, imageView.bounds.size.height);

     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

     [imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
     [myImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,12,myImage.size.width,myImage.size.height)];
     myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

     [imageView setImage:myImage];
     [self->_newbutton setImage:[imageView image] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I have created property for this,and i accessing it in the same to disable it.But when is do so i get and error saying 'Message sent to a deallocated instance'. I am using the following code to disable it.

```
 [self->_newbutton setEnabled:No];
```

Comment: Any reason for `self->_newbutton` rather than `self._newbutton`?

Comment: In class.h
UIButton *_newbutton;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *newbutton;×Only one additional

Comment: Have a read about objective C dot syntax, it's not C++ way of accessing pointer.

Comment: The issue was with Autoreleasing the new button. Before getting called the new button was getting rleased.so it was becoming a Zobie object. so was causing a crash.Thank u guys for u help...............

Answer (score 1):

Generate Button with `_newbutton`

```
_newbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Also set image with `_newbutton`

```
[_newbutton setImage:[imageView image] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then set disable as

```
[self._newbutton setEnabled:No];
```

Comment: The issue was with Autoreleasing the new button. Before getting called the new button was getting rleased.so it was becoming a Zobie object. so was causing a crash.Thank u very much.....